# How to match case insensitive patterns with ls?

Tags: shell, ls, wildcards, case-sensitivity

I would like to list all files matching a certain pattern while ignoring the case.

For example, I run the following commands:

```
ls *abc*
```

I want to see all the files that have "abc" as a part of the file name, ignoring the case, like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mtk mtk 0 Sep 21 08:12 file1abc.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mtk mtk 0 Sep 21 08:12 file2ABC.txt
```

#### Note

I have searched the man page for case, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This is actually done by your shell, not by `ls`.

In `bash`, you'd use:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
```

and *then* run your command.

Or in `zsh`:

```
unsetopt CASE_GLOB
```

Or in yash:

```
set +o case-glob
```

and then your command.

You might want to put that into `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` or `.yashrc`, respectively.

Alternatively, with zsh:

```
setopt extendedglob
ls -d -- (#i)*abc*
```

(that is turn case insensitive globbing on a per-wildcard basis)

With ksh93:

```
ls -d -- ~(i:*abc*)
```

You want **globbing** to work different, not `ls`, as those are all files passed to `ls` by the shell.

Comment: In bash, how to reset to original setting, If I use `shport -s nocaseglob` ?

Comment: @mtk: To *set* an option, you use `shopt -s`; to *unset* it, you use `shopt -u`. Alternatively, you can wrap everything in a subshell by using `( )` so that the setting doesn't affect the parent shell: `(shopt -s nocaseglob ; ls *abc*)`.

Comment: So there isn't any portable ways for this in POSIX or SUS or something like that (except for `[aA][bB][cC]`)?

Comment: Excellent solution, I can't believe I hadn't come across `shopt` command in the last 15 yrs of using bash!

Comment: Jfg956's answer is the right one (next one). Why changing the shell behaviour when you have a regexp for that?

Comment: @TimothyGu No, there is not.

Answer (score 33):

As explained by polemon, it is the shell (not ls) that extends `*abc*` to a list of files.  This is called **Pattern Matching**.

Aside from changing the whole Pattern Matching behavior to ignore case, you could use another form of pattern matching than the `*`.  The following would do what you want in bash:

```
ls *[aA][bB][cC]*
```

From bash man:

> [...]  Matches  any one of the enclosed characters.

This allows more fine grain matching where you could use `*[aA][bB]c*` to match `abc` or `ABc` but not `abC` or `ABC`.  Or an example in French, where I could want to match all instances of the `e` character:

```
ls *[eéèêëEÉÈÊË]*
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that approach quickly becomes unwieldy as the pattern gets longer. But for short things, it works.

Comment: @derobert: totally true, especially is (and it is probably the case) the shell has optimized the matching ignoring case by putting all the filenames and the match request in lower cases before comparing.  However, the `[...]` can be useful in many cases, and I though it was worth mentioning.

Comment: This is the right answer. Changing the shell behaviour is not.

Comment: If the locale is set properly, you should be able to use equivalence classes `[[=e=][=E=]]`.

Answer (score 21):

You can also add `-i` (--ignore-case) option to `grep` to get and the below output.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -l | grep -i abc
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Feb 25 20:41 fileabc.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Feb 25 20:41 fileABC.txt
```

Comment: Pattern matching has a better performance compared to grep because grep needs to gather everything and then filter. Has a noticeable difference when working with larger folder.

Comment: @Omi Additionally, regular expressions are for _text_, specifically _lines_ of text. Filenames may contain newlines.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is possible with ls, but you could use find instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*abc*'
```

Comment: .....Except that you have to remember that if you specify something that matches a directory, you're going to get the name of the directory, not the contents of it.  So it's not a 1:1 replacement for `ls`.  I believe that not allowing an `ls --ignore-case` is an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code:

```
LC_COLLATE=en_US ; export LC_COLLATE
ls *abc*
LC_COLLATE=C ; export LC_COLLATE
```

Comment: What is the LC_COLLATE variable for ? can you explain further.

Comment: click on the [link](http://teaching.idallen.org/net2003/06w/notes/character_sets.txt) to know about this @mtk

Answer (score 0):

You can GREP the file using `-i` which adds the insensitive option.

For example to find both `abc` and `ABC` you can run this command

```
    [root@mtk bin]# ls -l | grep -i abc
    640K -rw-r--r-- 1 mtk mtk 639K Sep 21 08:12 file1abc.txt
    676K -rw-r--r-- 1 mtk mtk 674K Sep 21 08:12 file2ABC.txt
```

Comment: Luis Perez I think you haven't used `-i` option anywhere in you command.

Comment: also [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425)

Answer (score -3):

In tcsh, set an alias in .aliases

```
alias lsnc "ls BS!* | sort -f "
```

("BS" = one "backslash"; I had to use this to get it to show up in my browser.)

and use `lsnc` instead of `ls`

In bash, try an alias in .bash_aliases like

```
lsnc() { ls $1 | sort -f ; }
```

With options to `ls`, e.g., `ls -l`, here is a simple fix:

tcsh:

```
alias lsncl "ls -l BS!* | sort -f -k 9"
```

bash:

```
lsncl() { ls -l $1 | sort -f -k 9 ; }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing a '`=`' after lsnocase?

Comment: Anthon:  The (revised) lsnc and lsncl work for me under tcsh and bash on both Cygwin and Ubuntu.  Note that for bash, I'm using a function, not an "alias" per se.  Lester

Comment: Anthon:  Yes, you likely can use alias in bash, like alias lsncl='ls -l $1 | sort -f -k 9'

Comment: This answer does not address the specific question which wants to pass the files passed to ls to be treated as a case-insensitive. If the shell passes passes *too few* files to `ls`, there's nothing `ls` and `sort` can can to fix the situation.  As noted in other answers, the problem needs to solved in the shell, not with an `ls` syntax.