# Is there an equivalent to bash's "nocaseglob" in ksh?

Tags: ksh, wildcards

I would like to do what is mentioned in 
[How to match case insensitive patterns with ls?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48770/how-to-match-case-insensitive-patterns-with-ls)

except for ksh. Is it possible to do it without any pain(regex)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 main implementations of `ksh`

- the original one from David Korn (AT&T `ksh`), with two main branches: `ksh88` and `ksh93` (and for `ksh93`, many version with new features added for each).
- `pdksh`, the public domain version (a free reimplementation of `ksh88` with which it is mostly compatible) which is the base upon which is built the `sh` on some BSDs like MirOS or OpenBSD (hence `mksh` and `oksh`).
- The `zsh` implementation. When called as `ksh`, `zsh` emulates the behavior of `ksh88` with many of the features of `ksh93` as well (and a few differences as well).

With `ksh93`:

```
print -r -- *.~(i:txt)
```

or

```
print -r -- ~(i)*.txt
```

With `ksh88` or `pdksh` and its derivatives such as `mksh`:

```
print -r -- *.[tT][xX][tT]
```

With zsh's implementation of `ksh`:

```
setopt nocaseglob
print -r -- *.txt
```

or

```
setopt extended_glob
print -r -- (#i)*.txt
```

Comment: That was very enlightening/informative. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

With out regex, no!

But parsing 'ls' output with grep shouldn't be as much pain (if at all).

```
ls | grep -i '*xxx*'
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is almost always a bad idea. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs