# case insensitive, list files in directory, ending in .jpg

Tags: bash, ls, wildcards, case-sensitivity

I'm trying to write an alias to list all the files in a directory ending in JP(E)G in its various forms. The ones I'm looking for it to recognise are .jpg .JPG .jpeg and .JPEG.

Is there a form of ls (or ***ls*** in combination with another command, such as find or grep) that will do this?

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

No. But then `ls` does not have a way to list file ending `.jpg` case sensitive or note. It is the shell that converts the `*.jpg` into a list of files, and passes this list to `ls`. Try `echo *.jpg`, to get some ideas of what the shell is doing.

## Long answer

You can use `find`: e.g. `find . -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg"`

or use grep e.g. `ls | grep -iE "[.]jpe?g$"`

or **set your shell to have case insensitive globs: `shopt -s nocaseglob`** (This works in Bash, see [How to match case insensitive patterns with ls?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48770/170373) for solutions for other shells.)

Answer (score 4):

Note that it's not `ls` that expands wildcards, it's the shell.

`bash` can make all its globs case insensitive with the `nocaseglob` option, but contrary to `ksh93` or `zsh` doesn't have a glob operator for having a single glob or part of a single glob case insensitive.

However, you can always do:

```
ls -ld -- *.[jJ][pP][gG]
```

Which also has the benefit of not leaving it up to the locale to decide what is the lower or upper case variant of a given letter (for instance, is the upper case variant of `gif` `GIF` or `GİF`?).

Or with the `extglob` option to also cover `jpeg`:

```
ls -ld -- *.[jJ][pP]?([eE)[gG]
```

With `zsh`, and with the `extendedglob` option (`set -o extendedglob`):

```
ls -ld -- *.(#i)jp(e|)g
```

With `ksh93`:

```
ls -ld -- *.~(i)jp?(e)g
```

Or:

```
ls -ld -- *.~(i:jp?(e)g)
```